# Configure RME TotalMix to record the PC's output into Audacity

Tags: audacity, cockos-reaper

I would like to record in Audacity or Reaper the output of my PC.
If you configured my PC to send all the sound to the output to ADAT(3+4)
[image]

I can't figure out how to say in TotalMix that this must be routed on any of the inputs I could record in Reaper of Audacity.

[image]
[image]

This is something really obvious to do with my former M-Audio Delta44. But with RME Babyface, I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the "Loopback" function, which is available in the hardware outputs tools:
[image]

This function reinject the signal sent to that hardware outputs to its corresponding hardware input. So here AN 1/2.

Attention: the VU meter of the hardware input does not reflect this, as it is only measuring what **physically** arrives in that input.

Now the signal sent to AN 1/2 can be recorded from audacity or any DAW:
[image]

See also the explanatory video: [RME Audio TotalMix FX - 09 Utilisation du Loopback](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvwiLIOYM5Y&list=PL0QKeSpeDQwHHxavw_H4iX8x8Bduh7hBl&index=9)